# Javascript - Values reset before returning

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, function

I'm trying make a function that returns the amount of wins a player have had based on a local database. However the values 'p1' and 'p2' seems to reset back to 0 every time they exit out of their loops.

```
function getAmountOfWins(player) {
var p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Filter WHERE player1='" + player + "'", [], function (tx, results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            current = results.rows.item(i);
            p1 = p1 + current.p1wins;
        }
    });
});
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Filter WHERE player2='" + player + "'", [], function (tx, results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            current = results.rows.item(i);
            p2 = p2 + current.p2wins;
        }
    });
});
console.log("Total Wins before return: " + (p1 + p2));
return p1 + p2;
}
```

In this case p1 and p2 seems to be reset to 0 when they exit out of 'db.transaction'. I'm pretty lost at how I keep the data so I can actually return it.

Anyone has a magic fix that prevents this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't reset. They were never set. The `executeSQL` and the `transaction` methods are Async. Which means you have to do somethin lik this:

```
function getAmountOfWins(player, callback) {
    // Call function, callback is executed after the query calculations
    getPlayerValues(1, player, function(p1num){
        // Call function, callback is executed after the query calculations
        getPlayerValues(2, player, function(p2num){
            // Call the original callback function
            callback( p1num + p2num );
        });
    });
}

// Get the player values
function getPlayerValues(playernr, player, callback){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Filter WHERE player" + playernr + "='" + player + "'", [], function (tx, results) {
            var p = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                current = results.rows.item(i);
                p = p + current.p2wins;
            }
            callback(p);
        });
    });
}
```

the call:

```
// Get the amount of wins, this is an async functionm with the callback
getAmountOfWins(player, function(value){
    console.log("Total Wins before return: " + (value));

});
```

Comment: Wao thanks! I must have never run into any async functions before using javascript. Thanks a lot for providing me with a commented answer!

Comment: However testing this and fiddling a little around I realize I still can't pull the value outside the function due to it also being async. Is there any way at all to somehow pull it out?
    wins = getAmountOfWins(player); ?

Comment: The call I provided is still async, if you want to use the `value` of the function I wrote, it has to be inside, as you can see the console.log does work. Move you code inside the function, and it will work.

Comment: Ahh yea I realized just now I can call it inside it self and still have access to the value as you demonstrated with getPlayerValues.
Apologies for the trouble, you've helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `executeSql` is asynchronous, since it accepts a callback function.

The body of the function you're giving it is executed at some point in the future, long after `console.log` as run. You need to refactor your code so that your `console.log` (and whatever other logic you want to include) are run by the callbacks passed to `executeSql`.